# Create table in Athena with auto load partitions

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I've created the table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
  `id` string COMMENT '', 
  `source` string COMMENT '', 
  `os` string COMMENT '')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `date` string COMMENT '')
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://.....';
```

But I have to tap `LOAD PARTITION` every time working this table. Is it possible to auto load partition for this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Partition Projection in Athena table which automatically handles partition.

You have to use **tblproperties** while creating the table.

Suppose , you have partitions from 2020-01-01 then extend this query in your create table statement.

```
TBLPROPERTIES
 (
     "projection.enabled" = "true",
     "projection.date.type" = "date",
     "projection.date.format"="yyyy-DD-mm",
     "projection.date.range"="2010-01-01,NOW"
    
 )
```

You can follow this link to know more--

[Partition Projection in Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html)